# Copy unmanaged data into managed array

Tags: c++-cli

I need to copy native (i.e. unmanaged) data (byte*) to managed byte array with C++/CLI (array).

I tried Marshal::Copy (data is pointed to by const void* data and is dataSize bytes)

```
array<byte>^ _Data=gcnew array<byte>(dataSize);
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy((byte*)data, _Data, 0, dataSize);
```

This gives error C2665: none of the 16 overloads can convert all parameters. Then I tried

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(new IntPtr(data), _Data, 0, dataSize);
```

which produces error C2664: parameter 1 cannot be converted from "const void*" to "__w64 int".

So how can it be done and is Marshal::Copy indeed the "best" (simplest/fastest) way to do so?

Comment: btw - "System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy((IntPtr)data, _Data, 0, dataSize);" gives error C2440 - cannot cast "const void*" to "System::IntPtr"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"[IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)" is just a wrapper around a "void *". You shouldn't need the new syntax, just use of the explicit conversion operator.

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy( IntPtr( ( void * ) data ), _Data, 0, dataSize );
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks, please see my comment above, though. However, it seems to work with "(IntPtr)(byte*) data. So, while it "works" now, the question remains if it could be done better. I'm afraid, there's no way to skip the copy.

Comment: @user Why are you casting it twice? You only need to case your "data" as an ( IntPtr ) because you have it declared as a "const void *". This is just making it fit the method signature for "Marshal.Copy", change your declaration of data to IntPtr and you won't need the cast.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change "data" from "const void*" because it comes like this from a third party lib. And, as mentioned above, (IntPtr)data gives error C2440 just like this snippet: "const void* vp; IntPtr ip=(IntPtr)vp;"

Comment: @User const void * data = ...; IntPtr ptr = IntPtr( ( void * ) data ); // now user ptr

Answer (score 15):

As you've noted, `Marshal::Copy` (and .NET in general), is not `const`-safe.

However, the usual C and C++ functions are.  You can write either:

```
array<byte>^ data_array =gcnew array<byte>(dataSize);
pin_ptr<byte> data_array_start = &data_array[0];
memcpy(data_array_start, data, dataSize);
```

or to avoid pinning:

```
array<byte>^ data_array =gcnew array<byte>(dataSize);
for( int i = 0; i < data_array->Length; ++i )
    data_array[i] = data[i];
```

Comment: I like to avoid pinning

Answer (score 12):

All these answers dance around the real misunderstanding in the original question..  The essential mistake made is that this code:

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(new IntPtr(data), 
                                                _Data, 
                                                0, 
                                                dataSize)
```

is incorrect.. you don't new (or gcnew) an IntPtr.  Its a value type.  One of the answers shows this, but it doesn't point out the original misunderstanding.  The correct code can be expressed this way:

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr((void *)data), 
                                                _Data, 
                                                0, 
                                                dataSize)
```

This confused me when I first started using these constructs also..

IntPtr is a C# struct.. a value type.

Answer (score 7):

The C++/CLI compiler is a bit obtuse about this.  The formal definition of IntPtr is "native integer", it is not a pointer type.  The C++ language however only allows conversion of void* to a pointer type.  The CLI supports pointer types but there are very few framework methods that accept them.  Marshal::Copy() doesn't.  One of the three IntPtr constructors does.

You have to whack the compiler over the head with a cast or by using the IntPtr constructor.  It is anybody's guess if this will still work on a 128-bit operating system, I'm not going to worry about it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

> System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(new
>   IntPtr((void*)data), _Data, 0, dataSize);

Pay attention to **(void*)** which **type-casts from (const void*)** so new IntPtr constructor can take it as argument.