# Can you convert vector<unsigned char> to byte[]?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Can you convert a `vector<unsigned char>` from C++/CLI to a `byte[]` in C#?

I looked far and wide but couldn't find any answer to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy unmanaged data into managed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403005/copy-unmanaged-data-into-managed-array)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A `std::vector<T>` is contiguous, that is to say `&v[i] == &v[0]+i` for `i<v.size()`. And on C++/CLI platforms (specifically), `unsigned char` is exactly 8 bits (a C# `byte`).