# Passing an array from unmanaged C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I'm new to C++/CLI wrapper to C#, I've some issues on passing array to C#.

Native c++

```
const double *NDimInversion::GetOutputAverage() const
{
    if ( mOutputOk )
        return mAvgY.data().begin();
    else
        throw runtime_error("Error in NDimInversion::GetOutputAverage(): output not available.");
}
```

Native header

```
const double *GetOutputAverage() const;
```

Wrapper header

```
public ref class NDimInversion
public: 
  array<double>^ GetOutputAverage();
```

Wrapper c++

```
array<double>^ NDimInversion::GetOutputAverage() {

    array<double> tempArr = nDimInversion->GetOutputAverage(); // ???? 

    const int SIZE = tempArr.size();
    array<double>^ tempReturn = gcnew array<double>(SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        tempReturn[i] = tempArr[i];
    }

    return tempReturn
};
```

I plan to convert the native return into CLI array, but I couldn't pass the array. 
Can you point me what am I missing?
Do I need to carry "const" keyword to CLI as well?

Comment: The native function does not tell you how large the array is.  Where that info is supposed to come from is not obvious, certainly not from size().  Rewrite the native function to return `std::vector<double>` and you'll have a shot at making it work.

Answer (score -1):

This describes how to [copy between managed and unmanaged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_IntPtr_System_Double___System_Int32_System_Int32_). 
Example [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403005/copy-unmanaged-data-into-managed-array):

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy( IntPtr( ( void * ) sourcePointer), targetManagedArray, 0, dataSize );
```

As mentioned in the comments, you absolutely need to know the number of items in the source array.